# set value of field using rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I need to set the value of a field in my form using rjs.

That field in question appears twice in my form and I want to set the value of the field found inside a particular div only.

The code below does not seem to work.

```
page[:mydiv_id][:book_bk_title].value = "myvalue"
```

My question is how do i set the value of a field by also specifying the div containing it. using rjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery:

```
var div_id = "mydiv";
$("#"+div_id+" :input[ID^='input_id']").val('Field Value');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I also need to specify the div_id.How do I do that?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your needs.